# Trouble getting a conditional call of a feature file to work in Karate

Tags: karate

Trouble getting a conditional call of a feature file to work in Karate.

Having trouble figure out why this syntax does not compile.  Any ideas?

```
* def authenticator = read('classpath:features/functions/oauth2.feature')
* def oauth = cloud_envs.includes(env) ? karate.call(authenticator) : {}
```

The `karate.call` works fine on it's own.  Just fails in the if-condition OR ternary, regardless of what I try.

The error is:

```
* def oauth = cloud_envs.includes(env) ? karate.call(authenticator) : {}0.031
js
js failed:
>>>>
01: cloud_envs.includes(env) ? karate.call(authenticator) : {}
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (call) 
on com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge@8216db failed due to: no applicable 
overload found (overloads: [Method[public java.lang.Object 
com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.call(java.lang.String)], 
Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.call(boolean,java.lang.String)], Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.call(java.lang.String,org.graalvm.polyglot.Value)], 
Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.call(boolean,java.lang.String,org.graalvm.polyglot.Value)]], arguments: [JavaObject[classpath:features/functions/oauth2.feature (com.intuit.karate.core.Feature)] (HostObject)])
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

classpath:features/group_info_queries.feature:10
```

Seems like it should work since this call, in the same test, works:

```
* def token = cloud_envs.includes(env) ? 'Bearer ' + oauth.accessToken : 'n/a'
```

Comment: no idea. cannot replicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work this way.  Not sure why I had to hack it like this.  Ugly but it works.

```
* eval
"""
var tokResponse = karate.call('functions/oauth2.feature')
var emptyResponse = {tokResponse: ''}
if (tokResponse) {
  karate.set('oauth', tokResponse)
} else {
  karate.set('oauth', emptyResponse)
}
"""
```